# How to add relationship in vtiger 7 custom module

Tags: crm, vtiger, vtigercrm

My VTiger custom module is showing nothing in Relationships tab. How i can add relationship to other modules e.g Leads.

I've created the module using console.php

Thanks

Comment: there are two ways, first using db and second using script. I prefer php script creating in root dir where your index.php of the vtiger is. and after creating that script we should run that using browser. If you want the code to establish relationship between two module then i can post the code. but try first on your own. very easy if you go through the documentation, i have done in vtiger 7. and its does not matter whether you created your module using console.php or php script like me. relation can be established at the time of module creation and also can be done after creation.

Comment: do some research and try on your own first little bit. and then I will post if you still need, see documentation and vtiger discussion forum.

Comment: right! but i have just started with vTiger and understanding the structure. i did googled but didn't find a way. Is there any link you can share where i can find complete documentation with examples. Thanks

Comment: there is no complete documentation for vtiger 7. I have gone through the existing documentation and googled a lot and slowly figured out vtiger. and how about the following answer??

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here first method using PHP code.

Create a php file into your root dir of vtiger as `create_relation.php`.

```
<?php
/*
create_relation.php
Create this file into your root directory of vtiger i.e. vtigercrm/
and then run this file directly using your browser 
for example localhost/vtigercrm/create_relation.php
*/
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');
$moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('Leads');
$accountsModule = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('new_module');
$relationLabel  = 'New_modules';
$moduleInstance->setRelatedList(
      $accountsModule, $relationLabel, Array('ADD') //you can do select also Array('ADD','SELECT')
);

echo "done";
```

Using this vtiger_relatedlists table, relationships are being established

Read the comments on above code and also update the DB table `vtiger_relatedlists` if needed. This is the table where you have to make sure the `relationfieldid` field (column) correct there in this table(vtiger_relatedlists).